# output array (KEY > VALUE) input fields

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array:

```
$abc=array(
    'car'=>'Mercedes',
    'year'=>array ('first'=>1991, 'last'=> 2014),
    'holder'=>'Jake'
    ......so on, with deep-level arrays
);
```

i want a function to recursively check nested array and output input for each final KEYNAME and KEYVALUE:

`<input name="KEYNAME" value="KEYVALUE" />`

Comment: I'd expect a better question from a user with your reputation...

Comment: i'd expect a better understanding of question from a user with your reputation. :)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can't figure out what type of output you want?

Comment: So, what stops you?

Comment: can you please paste the output for the above input because you have array inside array so atleast paste expected outcome for all those what shown in input. It will be much clear then

Comment: Please write code for me because I don't want to do it myself. Did I get that right?

Comment: Isn't it?  `echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Question answered, that was what i expected.

Comment: You do not show any effort of trying, researching or coding at all in your question. Just a poor question. And a question which is answered within minutes mostly are not of the best quality.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($abc as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
            echo $key2.': <input name="'.$key2.'" value="'.$value2.'" />';
        }
    } else {
        echo $key.': <input name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'" />';
    }
}
```

Result:

```
car: <input name="car" value="Mercedes">
first: <input name="first" value="1991">
last: <input name="last" value="2014">
holder: <input name="holder" value="Jake">
```